# html5 video "poster" attribute does also work as a image fallback?

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-video

In a ReactJS context, I initially created an image fallback for my video tag by doing:

```
<video ref={lazyVideo} autoPlay={"autoplay"} playsInline muted loop>
  <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1080" height="768" />
  <img src="/images/video-ph.png" width="1080" height="768" title="Your browser does not support the videos" />
</video>
```

then I wanted to lazy load the video so I used a `useEffect`, and added a `poster` image to the video, and I wonder now if the `poster` attribute works also as a fallback and I don't need the `img` anymore? I can't find infos about it

```
<video ref={lazyVideo} autoPlay={"autoplay"} playsInline muted loop poster="/images/video-ph.png">
 <source data-src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1080" height="768" />
 <img src="/images/video-ph.png" width="1080" height="768" alt="Your browser does not support the videos" />
</video>
```